# javascript regex must include 1 dot in the middle but no dots in beginning or end

Tags: javascript, regex

this is what I've been able to find so far `/^[^.].*[^-_.]$/` I can't get the required middle dot to work, however. I tried adding `[\.*]` to the middle but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning, repeat a non-dot one or more times with `+`, then match a literal dot with `\.`, then match anything with `.*` up until the final character:

```
^[^.]+\..*[^-_.]$
```